# Como faço para essa função abrir url em nova aba na opção link randômico

Tags: javascript, url, random, aba

```
links = new Array("<www.google.com","https://www.youtube.com/","portal.trademap.com.br");
tamanho = links.length;

nRand = Math.floor((Math.random() * tamanho ));

document.write ("<p><a href='"+links[nRand]+"' > BOTÃO </a></p>");
```

Answer (score 1):

Para abrir um link em uma nova aba basta adicionar a propriedade **target="_blank"**

```
document.write ("<p><a target='_blank' href='"+links[nRand]+"' > BOTÃO </a></p>");
```